# SaxonC EE 11.2's "SaxonProcessor::newXslt30Processor()" returns a Debug Assertion Failed : "vector subscript out of range"

Tags: c++, xslt, saxon, saxon-c

I am using the cpp and hpp files from the C API in Saxon EE , I just compiled and ran these lines :

```
SaxonProcessor* processor = new SaxonProcessor(false);
Xslt30Processor* xslt = processor->newXslt30Processor();
```

It shows the error when I create a XSLT30Processor.
Also I'm not using a license.

Ive Debugged it and the furthest I could get to before the it calls JNI methods is line 36 of Xslt30Processor.cpp :

```
Xslt30Processor::Xslt30Processor(SaxonProcessor * p, std::string curr) {

    proc = p;
    jitCompilation = false;
    exception = nullptr;
    /*
     * Look for class.
     */
    cppClass = lookForClass(SaxonProcessor::sxn_environ->env,    \\ It fails here
            "net/sf/saxon/option/cpp/Xslt30Processor");

    jobject tempcppXT = createSaxonProcessor2(SaxonProcessor::sxn_environ->env, cppClass,
            "(Lnet/sf/saxon/s9api/Processor;)V", proc->proc);
    if(tempcppXT) {
        cppXT = SaxonProcessor::sxn_environ->env->NewGlobalRef(tempcppXT);
        SaxonProcessor::sxn_environ->env->DeleteLocalRef(tempcppXT);

    } else {
        createException("Error: Failed to create the Xslt30Processor internal object");

    }

#ifdef DEBUG
    jmethodID debugMID = SaxonProcessor::sxn_environ->env->GetStaticMethodID(cppClass, "setDebugMode", "(Z)V");
    SaxonProcessor::sxn_environ->env->CallStaticVoidMethod(cppClass, debugMID, (jboolean)true);
    
#endif

    if(cppXT == nullptr) {
        createException();
    }

    if(!(proc->cwd.empty()) && curr.empty()){
        cwdXT = proc->cwd;
    } else if(!curr.empty()){
        cwdXT = curr;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does compilation *fail*? Or do you get a warning? On which platform do you work, which compiler do you use? Did you manage to compile and run the samples like transform.c or like `testXSLT30.cpp` from the Saxon download without such assertions?

Comment: Im on windows , im using the windows cl compiler

Comment: yes Transform.exe works , but i need my C++ code to work

Comment: Compilation doesnt fail , i dont get any warnings from saxon , only when I run the program then it shows the error as a window

Comment: Can you try to see whether the `samples\cppTests\testXSLT30.cpp` (from the Saxon installation directory) compiles and runs for you?

Comment: When i try to build it it gives an error :  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class _jobject * __cdecl cppExtensionFunction::cppNativeCall

Comment: The installed build bat for Windows needs a fix, I am afraid, you can download a fixed build bat from https://saxonica.plan.io/attachments/55352

Comment: The TestXslt30 somehow works

Comment: Good, can you try to model your C++ code using SaxonC after it, to see whether that helps avoiding the error you get?

Comment: They have the exact same two lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out , my cpp files werent including the files in the write order. I cant beleive it

Comment: You did not really answer you question, your problem was not related to the code you published so the best is simply to remove your question